# Make input fields readonly with values based on another input field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 3 input fields in the create user form. Based on the selection of status, I want to make the next 2 fields read-only with specific values.
So If the user selects "Full-Time" for Status, the next 2 fields should become read-only with values 5 and 7.6 respectively. For any other selection, it should remain as a normal input field for the user to enter values.
How can I achieve this? Would highly appreciate any help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listener events and jquery's method attr to handle the state of the other two text boxes. Here is an example.

```js
function changeVal(e) {
            console.log(e.target.value)
            if (e.target.value == "Full Time") {
                $("#workingday").val(5)
                $("#workinghour").val(7.6)
                $("#workingday").attr("readonly", true)
                $("#workinghour").attr("readonly", true)
            } else {
                $("#workingday").val("")
                $("#workinghour").val("")
                $("#workingday").attr("readonly", false)
                $("#workinghour").attr("readonly", false)
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td>Working Day in weeks</td>
        <td>Working Hours Per Day</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select onchange="changeVal(event)">
                <option value="">--select--</option>
                <option value="Full Time">Full Time</option>
                <option value="other">other value</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="workingday" name="workingday" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="workinghour" name="workinghour" value="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @StillLearning, can this help you? Could you accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?

Answer (score 0):

add runat attribute to Status

```
runat="server"
```

then take the value of Status and compare it to set the parameters of the other fields

```
String statustxt = Status.Value;
if(Equals(statustxt, targettxt) {
workingdays.Text = "5";
workingdays.ReadOnly = true;
workinghours.Text = "7.6";
workinghours.ReadOnly = true; }
```

You can also set Editable = false

Comment: Let me know if this format worked for you, runat server enables you to work with the inputs in real time.